# MSYS starts in wrong root directory

Tags: msys

I accidentally closed MSYS while compiling CMake project and now MSYS is broken. When MSYS starts up it prints sh-3.1$ instead of Username$ like it used to. It also creates a directory called etc in the /home directory. Any MSYS commands don't work neither (ls, cmp, etc.).

My best quess is that for some reason it thinks /home is my root directory. Maybe the compiling messed up some environment variable or something like that?

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all the MinGW files and reinstalling helped.